# How to solve for $a$?

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

How to solve this inequality for $a$?

$\cos^2x + (a+1)\cos x+a<0 : x \in R$

This what i have tried so far.

By factoring, $(\cos x+1)(\cos x+a)<0$

Since, $(\cos x+1)\in [0,2] , (\cos x+a)<0$

After this I can't proceed any further. Is my approach any good in this case?  Or is there a better alternative for this?

Comment: Hint: $-1 \le \cos(x) \le 1$. Under what conditions is $\cos(x) + 1 > 0$ or $\cos(x) + 1 < 0$? What values of can $a$ have in these cases for the inequality to hold?

Comment: @AlkaKadri is $a<-1$ correct?

Comment: Note if $x = \pi$ then $\cos^2 x + (a+1)\cos x + a = 1 -a - 1 + a = 0 \not < 0$ regardless of what $a$ is.

Comment: Certainly! You've correctly identified that $\cos(x)  + 1 \ge 0$. In order to have the product be negative, we need $\cos(x) + a < 0$, and since $\cos(x) \le 1$, $a < -1$ will always give this. Note that at $x = \dots, -3\pi, -\pi, \pi, 3\pi, \dots$ we exactly have $(\cos(x) + 1)(\cos(x) + a) = 0$, so there may be something missing from the original question...

Comment: "so there may be something missing from the original question" Or not.  "there are no values of $a$ so that this inequality is true for all $x\in \mathbb R$" is a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right so go on:

$(\cos x + 1)(\cos x + a) < 0$ so either:

1) $\cos x + 1 > 0$ and $\cos x + a < 0$ or

2) $\cos x + 1 < 0$ and $\cos x + a > 0$.

1) can be true if $x \ne (2k+1) \pi$ and if $a < - \cos x$.  But this will not always be true.  If $a \le -1$ the will only not be true with $x = (2k+1)\pi$.

2) can never be true

However as $\cos x + 1 = 0$ is a possibility  so there is no $a$ where this is always true.  So there is not solution.